# Monitorar alterações no aplicativo

Tags: java, android, services

Preciso de uma classe que fique escutando por alguma alteração na aplicação (ou alteração externa).

Fiz uma classe que estendeu da classe `Service`, porém percebo que entra no método `onStartCommand` apenas uma vez.

Estou fazendo algo errado?

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e("--> ", "onStartCommand");
      return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Minha sugestão é criar "estados" possíveis de conclusão (ok, erro, etc.), ou qualquer outra alteração que você queira monitorar, que um serviço externo possa gerar na execução e fazer o serviço armazenar esses valores numa chave de `SharedPreferences` de acordo com o estado desejado, pois ela poderá ser acessada na Activity.

Na aplicação você implementa na sua Activity um `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` e passa a "escutar" as alterações na chave de preferência especificada acima dentro do método `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` dessa interface.

Maiores detalhes de como implementar na documentação oficial:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html